# Referencing Function from another ReactJS Page for Validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am currently writing my first React Project for a class assignment. I am trying to make a login page that navigates to a new dashboard page. I do not want any fancy security, so I wanted it just to have "if password === this password then go to dashboard, if not then error message.

I have the button working fine without validation, and I have my handlers for the text input working as I can display what is typed by using `this.state.username` and `this.state.password` in my login-form.js file.

The problem I can't figure out is how to reference/use those states in my login-button.js file so I can create that if statement validator? Can anyone help?

Here is my login-form.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./login-form.css";
import logo from './../../logo-beesecure-2-tm.png';
import Login_btn from './../login-button/login-button';

class Login_Form extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = { username: '', password: '' };
    }

    handleChange = ({ target }) => {
       this.setState({ [target.name]: target.value });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='login-container'>
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <p>LOGIN</p>
                <form onSubmit="" className="login-form">
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="Username"
                        name="username"
                        value={this.state.username}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />

                    <input 
                        type="password" 
                        placeholder="Password"
                        name="password"
                        value={this.state.password}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}         
                    />


                </form>
                <Login_btn />

                <h2>Your username is: {this.state.username}</h2>
                <h2>Your password is: {this.state.password}</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Login_Form;
```

And here is my login-button.js file:

```
import './login-button.css';
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Login_Form from '../login-form/login-form';

function Login_btn() {
    let history = useHistory();

    function handleClick() {
      history.push("/dashboard");
    }

    return (
        <button className="Login-Button" onClick={handleClick}>Login</button>
    );
}

export default Login_btn;
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in the states from your `<Login_Form />` into your `<Login_btn />` by using props like so:

```
<Login_btn username={this.state.username} password={this.state.password} />
```

Then you can reference the props in your `<Login_btn />`:

```
function Login_btn(props) {
    let history = useHistory();

    function handleClick() {
      const { username, password } = props;
      history.push("/dashboard");
    }

    return (
        <button className="Login-Button" onClick={handleClick}>Login</button>
    );
}
```

You can read more about props here: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you so much! Turns out I didn't need to reference that page in my login-button.js either as I had previously. Thanks again!